# PXUIView pxStyleChildren crash

Tags: pixate

Just noticed this crash... SIGABRT ABORT at 0x38d141f0

```
objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 116
-[UIWebDocumentView _updateSubviewCaches] + 36
-[UIWebDocumentView subviews] + 86
-[PXUIView pxStyleChildren]
-[PXUIView layoutSubviews]
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Can you paste your Pixate CSS?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help... but here it goes http://pastebin.com/CDnsE7V9

Comment: What version of Pixate and what version of iOS is this running under?

Comment: Currently we are using 2.0.1

Comment: It seems that this is happening when the device is running low on memory.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, this crash is usually caused by having syntax in your CSS that Pixate can't process correctly.

Try removing the commas from `background-inset` and `background-size` in your `.button-search-cancel` selector.

```
.button-search-cancel{
  background-inset:15px 6px;
  background-size:13px 32px;
  background-image:url(ButtonSearchCancel.png);
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:700;
}
```

If that doesn't work, start by commenting out all your CSS and see if it still crashes. Then comment out half of it, then a quarter of it, etc. until you can narrow down where the issue is. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Hi again, I forgot to say that I cannot reproduce this issue and it was raised by one of my clients. Anyway... I'm not sure if that is the problem... Just looked to the documentation again (http://www.pixate.com/docs/framework/ios/latest/style-reference/values.html#size) and it says that we should separate the values with a comma.